# Sequence with two first variables

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have following problem:

I have a sequence: $10, 15, 5, 10, 5, ....$

First item is $10$ and second is $15$, every next item can be calculated from formula: $$a_n=\lvert a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\rvert$$

And now I have to calculate $124$th item, can somebody help me, I would like to create formula for calculating that without need to calculate previous items.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you continue to calculating the items you will find,
$$10,15,5,10,5,5,0,5,5,0,5,5,0,5,5,0,....$$
Therefore, the sequence, after its 6th item, has only the specific values $0,5,5$ which is repeated periodically. Therefore, we have
$$a_7=a_{10}=a_{13}=....=a_{7+3n}=0\,\,\,n\geq0$$
and
$$a_5=a_6=a_8=a_9=a_{11}=a_{12}=...=a_{5+3n}=a_{6+3n}=5\,\,\,n\geq0$$
Therefore, since $124=7+3(39)$, we find $a_{124}=0$.

In General we can write
$${a_1} = 10\,,\,\,{a_2} = 15\,,\,{a_3} = 5\,,\,{a_4} = 10\,$$
and for $n\geq 5$,
$${a_n} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{\bmod \left( {n,3} \right) = 1}\\
5&{\bmod \left( {n,3} \right) = 0\,\,or\,\,2}
\end{array}} \right.$$
where the unction mod gives the reminder.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I meant. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Look at the followings. 
$$10,15,5,10,5,5,0,5,5,0,5,5,0,\cdots$$
Then, I'm sure you can find $a_{124}$. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, however I currently calculated that in my memory. But my question is more general, I would like to create a formula. Can you please help me?

Comment: @MaciejSzpakowski: Of course. Then, don't you notice something interesting (any pattern) from my hint?

Comment: After fourth number 5, 5, 0 begins to repeat. In the first place I thought that if 120 (124-4) is divisible by 3 the answer will be 0 (correct), however it is divisible by many different integers too hence I feel a bit lost.